# How I can change value of a page elements showing in a Webview in Electron

Tags: webview, electron

I don't understand How I can change value of elements of a page which is showing in a Webview. I need to fill forms showing in this webview with data I got on the local machine or a remote server with Http and Json response.
I can't determine if it's feasible and how.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I used the method ExecuteJavascript of the WebView and it works.....